# p5.js dragging objects incompatible with IE EDGE browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, p5.js, polyfills

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZYf5.png)

[image]

hello,

i am using p5.JS (0.10.2/p5.js) and having trouble with IE and Edge (Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0) browsers when it comes to dragging a shape (works fine on chrome). even when i use the official p5.JS on Edge it drags the whole page sometimes (as seen on the attached pic).
this is the link to an example of code in the p5 editor:
https://p5js.org/examples/input-mouse-functions.html

i have tried some Polyfills with no success.
for some reason when i click on the canvas with the mouse before dragging the shape - it works just fine.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to test your sample code with Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 and Internet Explorer 11.

This is the result I got with MS Edge browser.

[image]

I also seen the behavior of dragging the whole page sometimes.

In IE 11 browser, code did not worked.

If we refer the documentation then we can see that,"Canvas blend modes are not supported in IE." This is the reason that it is not working in IE browser.

Reference:

[P5.JS Supported browsers](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/contributor_docs/supported_browsers.md)

For MS Edge browser, I agree with you that we need to click on the canvas before dragging the shape. As we cannot fix this issue from MS Edge browser or by modifying the code, I suggest you to provide the feedback to P5.JS by creating the new issue on their GitHub page. Here. [Create new issue for P5.JS](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen)